# How to read texts inside images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say i uploaded that image in my app:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW3Kz.png)

is there a way to "read" that text and convert it into a string?

Comment: It’s called [Optical Character Recognition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

theres a dependency you can use although there are bunch of approaches to perform text recognition using ML OCR algorithms.

you can start by using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/learning_text_recognition)
and i would recommend to check [this](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/ocr-in-flutter-5144ed361239)

Hope it helps somehow.